# Слово "шпана"

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Интересно узнавать происхождение просторечных слов и жаргонизмов. Например, слово "шпана", откуда оно взялось?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, (мелкая) *шпана* - слово жаргонное, и его происхождение следует связывать с немецким **span** (щепка, щепа, лучина, стружка).
Шпон - тонкие листы древесины...
Можно ли сюда притянуть шпандырь (spannriemen - специальный сапожный ремень, используемый для удобствы работы) не совсем понятно. Spann - *подъем ноги*.
Первая версия лучше по смыслу подходит, ср. слово *отщепенец* - отколовшийся от большинства народа маргинальный субъект. Словарь Ушакова :

> ОТЩЕПЕНЕЦ 
> отщепенца, м. (книжн. презрит.). Человек, отколовшийся от какого-н. общественного коллектива, отвергнутый обществом; отступник.

Comment: Совпадение по звучанию , само по себе , ещё не означает этимологическую связь . Возьмём два слова : существительное "виселица" и глагол "веселиться" . Если по вашей логике ШПАНА=ОТЩЕПЕНЕЦ , то , стало быть , когда вешали какого-нибудь "отщепенца" народ впадал в радостный экстаз , то бишь , "виселился"=веселился . Тут явно не ОТЩЕПЕНЕЦ , а что-то иное .

Answer (score 3):

Из этимологического словаря Черных.

Как областное слово (с различными оттенками значений) отмечается с начала 1900-х годов (Красноярский край, Сибирь), также "шпанка" — воры, бродяги, коренное тюремное население, презрительное прозвище арестантов.

В общерусском языке отмечено с начала 1920-х. Вероятно из говоров, а там из блатного арго; скорее всего, немецкого происхождения: Spanelder (арго) — бродяги, род воров, от нем. spannen — подстерегать. Оформление по образцу более раннего слова "шантрапа".

Comment: Вот это конкретная версия : spenedler - spannen - шпана ! Считаю ваш ответ точным и поддерживаю его .Но  ШАНТРАПУ Вы , матушка ,  всунули сюда не по делу . "Шантрапа" соответствует французскому "не будет петь" . Когда хормейстеры-французы отбирали крепостных детей в барские хоры , не годных по голосовым данным они отбраковывали именно этими словами . В дальнейшем , у не понимавших по-французски ШАНТРАПА приобрело расширительный смысл .

Answer (score 1):

Что-то только сейчас этот вопрос заметил.

А у меня есть версия, что шпана<шпанка<шпанская

> ШПА́НСКИЙ, шпанская, шпанское (от нем. spanisch - испанский). Входит в
>   состав ботанических, зоологических, сельскохозяйственных и
>   иных названий (спец.). Шпанская вишня (сорт вишен). Шпанская мушка (небольшой жучок, а также пластырь из порошка, который приготовляется
>   из высушенного жучка). Шпанская овца (порода овец). Шпанская ромашка.
>   Шпанская курица.

(с) Ушаков.

Возможно через идиш, но значение явно не столь далекое, как в других версиях, скорее всего тут дикий нрав и бродяжничество всего связанного со "шпанским", домысливать не хочу, оставляю версию неподтвержденной.

Answer (score 0):

Есть одна версия. Шпаной начали называть испанских туристов, которые отличались вызывающе громким и эмоциональным, невоспитанным поведением. *Los españoles* —испанцы. Затем слово укоренилось как определение асоциальных личностей.

Answer (score -1):

Попробую выстроить свой логический ряд по поводу происхождения этого слова. Кто такие «шпана»? – Это дворовая группировка, как правило, хулиганистого, криминального характера, состоящая, в основном, из молодых людей допризывного возраста. Есть интересное слово «шпиндель», пришедшее из немецкого языка и означающее буквально «веретено»,  а в современных технических устройствах этим словом называются вращающиеся валы. И есть слова  «шпендель», «шпендрик» - маленький человек, крутящийся, путающийся под ногами: « А ну, брысь отсюда, шпендель!» Вполне вероятно, что какой-нибудь мастер, чинивший ткацкие станки и знавший, что веретено – это шпиндель, мог называть любопытных детишек, вертящихся вокруг него, этим словом.  «Шпана» же для меня, представляется сборищем «шпендиков», подобно: брат – братва. И  вот ещё интересная информация, взятая мной из описаний старославянской азбуки: «Низшая часть азбуки начинается с буквы Ша. Истинный смысл этой буквы можно выразить такими словами как «шваль», «ничтожество» или «врун». Часто в предложениях они использовались для указания всей низменности человека, которого называли шабала, что обозначает врун и пустомеля. Еще одно слово, происходящее от буквы Ша, «шабендать», что значит суетиться по пустякам. А особенно гнусных людей называли словом «шаверень», то есть шваль или ничтожный человек». От себя приведу ещё пару примеров: шобла(ударение на «о»), шабла(ударение на второе «а»), шушара.

Comment: Дорогой Саша ! Вы опять выглядите соответственно второй половине вашего ника . Ранее , в другом вопросе от вашей фантазии пострадали труженики лесной отрасли , а теперь вы взялись за текстильщиков ...! А , если бы просветитель Кирилл мог прочесть вашу  философию насчет местоположения буквы Ша в славянской азбуке , он разломал бы свой гроб и написал гневное опровержение вашей демагогии .

Comment: Спасибо. Ваши комментарии - человека вежливого и образованного - бесценны!

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, что появление этого жаргонизма, имеющего в фене значение "сброд воришек", восходит к тому времени, когда после присоединения Северного Причерноморья к России евреи-ашкенази, проживавшие прежде в Малороссии и поселившиеся на новых землях, вошли в соприкосновение с евреями-сефардами, осевшими после изгнания из Испании в западных пределах Блистательной Порты. Первые, из коих состояли воровские сообщества, могли заметить в повадках "подрастающей смены" нечто характерное для поведения южных соплеменников, которые, ктомуже, и сами могли быть причастны к преступной деятельности. 
 Последних условно вполне можно было назвать "испанцами" [по-еврейски (идиш) Spanieren]. 
В пользу такого предположения косвенно может служить имеющееся в том же арго слово "барыга" (скупщик краденного), без сомнения происходящее из ладино — староиспанского языка, используемого сефардами (barrigа — пузо, следовательно, сам скупщик — "пузило").
При этом важно помнить и о часто встречающейся в фене игре слов, например: "легавый"— это и уподобление псу охотничьей породы, и древнееврейский этноним (легави), указывающий на жителя ненавистного евреям Египта ливийского происхождния; "мусер"— слово из идиш, имеющее значение "поучающий, читающий наставления", но вместе с тем, это и "мусор", в данном случае — "отброс общества".

Comment: Фантазии, однако. Старайтесь делать ответ  более конкретным, содержательным и аргументированным, а так он воспринимается именно как мусорный.

Answer (score -2):

Ответ находится в самом слове ,,шпана,, - ш/пана - что означает каждая буква мы забыли , но слово пан легко узнаваемо - скорее всего это ,.шестёрки,, самого пана или те кто под этого пана ,,косит,, .. Слово ,,паника,,из  того же ряда - известно кто поднимает первый панику - изнеженные дамочки ,,пани,, ..

Comment: Полная ерунда ! Уже хотя бы по тому , что в зонах , насколько я знаю , не "паны" , а "паханы" . Изложите эту вашу версию упоминаемым Вами "шестёркам" , и они ответят Вам , что Вы просто нахватались верхушек и в фене ни хрена не смыслите .

Comment: Одна уже ответила